# Android Studio latest version 3.4.1 not implement any latest dependency.?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-support-library

**I tried below to add below dependencies(latest version) in my project.**

*For Network:*

**implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.0.0-RC1'**

*For scalable size:*

implementation 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.6'

with latest version i am unable to sync the project but when i try with old version it's work perfect.

**ERROR LOG:**

```
ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath':
Could not resolve com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.0.0-RC1.
```

**ROOT LEVEL build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.31'
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    google()
    jcenter()
    }
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}}allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()

}}task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir}
```

**APP LEVEL build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
compileSdkVersion 28

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.kotlinapp"
    minSdkVersion 22
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }}}dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
//for size
implementation 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.6'
//for network call
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.0.0-RC1'
}
```

what the issue with latest version of **Android Studio ?**

Comment: add error stacktrace

Comment: add your root level build.gradle

Comment: please share the error logs, whats the issue you face?

Comment: @AsadChoudhary already added in to question

Comment: Its not issue about Android Studio, Check stable version for that dependency and update it.

Comment: @PratikButaniAndroidDev  i use stable version of dependency